# How to structure a Jenkins Pipeline with multiple git repositories

Tags: git, jenkins, github

Our application code is split across two Git repositories, web (.NET) and frontend (Angular). We need to build both separately (can be in parallel, but separate build processes), then upload artifacts to S3, from where we can deploy.

If we only had one Git repository, I'd dump a `Jenkinsfile` in there and go. However, given that we need both repositories to build before moving on to deployment, should we create a third ("control") repository that contains a `Jenkinsfile` which:

- Triggers both the web and frontend builds via their respective `Jenkinsfile`s, each of which will compile / run tests / upload artifacts.
- When both builds have finished successfully, manages the deploy to the webserver.

Does this sound sane? If not, what would be more sensible? (NB We do use GitHub, if the Organizational Plugin is of any use.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to use a control project sounds sane to me.

It seems like the downstream projects could be built and tested independently of each other and only need to be built in conjunction when a deployment/release of the entire project is taking place.

With that in mind, yes, you could trigger the top level job which builds the downstream jobs in parallel and waits for their statuses.  Seeing a good build from both downstream jobs would trigger the deployment.